# The symmetric difference using unions and intersections?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was going through the symmetric difference and the forumla I found in the literature is :

$A \Delta B = (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$

Is it also correct to say

$A  \Delta B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$ ?

Comment: Yes, the two are equivalent.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I tried different examples and produced the same result; Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are equivalent.

$A \Delta B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$

[image]

Here, $A \Delta B$ is colored portion.

---

$A \cup B$ is [image]
$A \cap B$ is [image]
Substracting both we get the $A \Delta B$
[image]

Therefore both are same.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way as the operation of union is defined using the "***inclusive or***" operator, the symmetric difference is defined using the "***exclusive or***".

Exclusive or ( let's use the symbol : w )   " adds" something to inclusive or ( v) : when I say  (A w B) I mean two things :

- A v B : one at least of the two propositions is true, they are not both false
- ~ (A&B) : one at least is false, they are not both true.

So  the set : A Delta B is the set of all x such that

- x belongs to A OR x belongs to B, that is, x belongs to A U B
- ***and*** x does not belong both to A and to B, that is ***x does not belong to A Inter B***.